# MATLAB: permission denied when trying to create an .mp4 file

Tags: matlab, mp4

here is my code:

```
myFolder = 'C:\Users\Authorised User\Documents\MATLAB\OilDropForceImages\OilDropForceImagesResized';
if ~isdir(myFolder)
    errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s', myFolder);
    uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
    return;
end

filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.png');
pngFiles = dir(filePattern);
for k = 1:length(pngFiles)
  baseFileName = pngFiles(k).name;
  fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
  fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
  imageArray = imread(fullFileName);
  imshow(imageArray, 'InitialMagnification', 77);  % Display image.
  drawnow; % Force display to update immediately.

end

A = imageArray;

vid0bj = VideoWriter('OilDropForceMovie.mp4','MPEG-4');
  open(vid0bj);
  writeVideo(vid0bj,A)

close(vid0bj)
```

the code runs well in MATLAB and shows what I want but when I try to save it as an .mp4 file so I can play it in windows media player I receive the error: Error using OilDropForceMovie (line 22)
Cannot create file OilDropForceMovie.mp4. Permission Denied.
does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, do you have write permissions to the directory where you are? I.e. `pwd`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the path looks like you are using a windows computer, when you open Matlab, run the program as administrator. For example, if the Matlab icon is on your desktop, right click and select 'run as administrator'

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certain that you don't have writing permissions to whichever is the active folder when you're running the script. What you should do it simply specify a full path when calling `VideoWriter`, so something like this should work:

```
vid0bj = VideoWriter('D:\WritableFolder\OilDropForceMovie.mp4','MPEG-4');
```

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this snag as well.

It was caused by the MP4 file being already open when re-running the script. I was doing some debugging and stopped the script halfway through before restarting it, so it didn't execute the close command near the end.

I solved it by putting this bit of code near the start of my script:

```
try
    close(video_file);
catch
end
```